# Is calling plt.subplots necessary when using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am curious whether the use of `plt.subplots` in the code below is necessary? Wouldn't we still be able to get the same graph if we didn't use it, and called `sns.heatmap` without the `ax` parameter? What exactly did using this method give us?

Normally, I thought that we were creating the heatmap directly with its graphic. It was the same in most sources on the internet, but I could not understand what the difference was from the examples outside.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[18, 13])
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True, fmt=".2f", ax=ax, cmap="magma")
ax.set_title("Correlation Matrix", fontsize=20)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`plt.subplots` is there to create a new figure with some configured axes. This isn't required per-se - there are other ways to create figure objects, and other ways to add axes to figures. This is just a convenient one-liner to do both in one go.

What *is* required is that you have a figure object with an axes. Without those, there nothing  to plot on.

And yet, as you mention, if you use seaborn without creating your own figure object and axes, it still works. So what gives?

The answer is that if you don't pass `sns.heatmap` an axes via its `ax` parameter, seaborn will try to fetch the "current axes" using [`matplotlib.pyplot.gca`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html). It just so happens that if there is no current axes on the current figure, `matplotlib.pyplot.gca` will create a new one in the background (and likewise, if there is no [current figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html), a new one will be automatically created during this process). It's that "hidden" axes that seaborn will plot on.

That drawback of doing it that way is that you don't have direct access the figure and axes objects that `matplotlib.pyplot.gca` created<sup>*</sup>. So, if you're going to need to interact with those objects, it's cleaner and more conveient to create them yourself up front.

---

<sup>*It is possible to access them using matplotlib's ["state machine" API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html). However, this can be a bit unwieldy. Sticking object-oriented API is generally simpler and cleaner.</sup>